# How to Override Prerequisites of a Target in Later part of Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to override the prerequisites of a target in later part of Makefile?

A common Makefile is used by multiple users.  To accommodate individual unique usage, an include directive is added at the end.

E.g. in common.make

```
SomeVar1 =

all: step5

step1:
    recipe1

step2: step1
    recipe2

step3: step2
    recipe3

step4: step3
    recipe4

step5: step4
    recipe5

-include local.make
```

Whenever necessary, individual user can override variables or even recipes from common.make in his/her own local.make.

However, it seems prerequisite from common.make can't be overridden in local.make.

E.g. if a user needs to skip step3 & step4, adding the following in local.make doesn't remove step4 as prerequisite for step5 target.

```
step5: step2
```

Does GNU make have some syntax to force override prerequisites of targets defined in earlier part of Makefile?

Perhaps, something like:

```
.OVERRIDE: step5: step2
```

The only way I can think of is to define prerequisites of each rule in common.make as variables.  But it will be unwieldy for large numbers of steps -- lots of variables to define and association/mapping of variable names to their steps requires separate documentations.

I would like to avoid the prerequisite-variable approach if possible.  Hopefully, GNU make has some syntax that can do so better.

Thank you for your help.

HCN

Comment: If the dependencies aren't common to the users, why have them in the common makefile?

Comment: @Beta, the dependencies are common for most users.  For them, common.make will be used as is.  But occasionally, a few users may need slightly different dependencies.  In other words, common.make is sufficiently good most of the time to most users, but may not be so all the time to all users.

Comment: There is another way, but it doesn't look any better than the prerequisite-variable approach, which frankly doesn't look any better than the desired `.OVERRIDE:` approach; you still need one statement specific to each rule you want to override, containing a description of the dependency relationship you want.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of a workaround that is not quite elegant as the desired hypothetical `.OVERRIDE:` but it doesn't require defining variable for each prerequisite in common.make.

Using the same common.gmake example, if a user needs to skip step3 & step4, but needs to add step1b & step1c between step1 & step2, his/her local.make will look as followed.

```
step1b: step1
    recipe1b

step1c: step1b
    recipe1c

step2: step1c

step3:
    :

step4:
    :
```

In addition, GNU make will also display warning messages about step3 & step4 targets being overridden, which is helpful.

```
local.make:10: warning: overriding commands for target `step3'
local.make:13: warning: overriding commands for target `step4'
common.make:12: warning: ignoring old commands for target `step3'
common.make:15: warning: ignoring old commands for target `step4'
```

Nevertheless, since this doesn't actually override dependencies, user has to force no-op to all dependencies to be skipped.  In this case, no-op is necessary for both step3 & step4 targets, where in real common.make, each skipped target may have multiple prerequisites.

This is the only gotcha I can think of.  I believe it'll work even with -j option for parallel execution.

Any potential pitfall in such local.make override usage that I haven't thought of, since I can't predict all possible GNU make options users may combine with local.make override?

HCN

Answer (score 1):

One way to get that override-like behavior is exploiting the pattern matching preferring "the most exact match". Making the original targets just a little ambiguous by a little pattern allows local.make to override with an exact match.

```
SomeVar1 =

all: step5

s%ep1:
    recipe1

s%ep2: step1
    recipe2

s%ep3: step2
    recipe3

s%ep4: step3
    recipe4

s%ep5: step4
    recipe5

-include local.make
```

If having `step5` in local.make it is more exact than `s%ep5`.

(I do not actually like this solution, but you do you, I just bring the tech.)

Comment: I didn't know about "the most exact match" behavior -- I learned a new thing today.  Nevertheless, target pattern seems risky as incorrectly named targets, e.g. steep5 & sleep5 will also match, instead of error.  Moreover, if pattern isn't careful chosen to ensure all targets in common.make remain unique, wrong target may be matched. E.g. if common.make has `s%ep5:` rule followed by `s%eep5:` rule, steep5 target will run `s%ep5:` recipe instead of `s%eep5:` recipe.

Comment: @HCN Yes, there are potential issues. However I believe it'll work fine 99% of the time since you'd have to apply this highly unusual trick in two locations unaware of each other with overlapping patterns. And if there is an overlap you can most likely alter once of the patterns with full backwards compatibility, e.g. `sl%ep`. So yeah you are right, but does it really matter, compared to (no) alternatives?

Comment: to catch some error you could add a %: that will match steep5 and warn the users. If you have courage or a script at hand just generate a list of srep5 sfep5 sgep5 syep5 (the 4 letters around t). Is is just for Azerty/Qwerty don't know about Dvorak/Bépo.

Answer (score 0):

Make has `?=` for overriding behavior:

```
-include local.make

# local.make definition of STEPX_PREREQS "overrides" below defaults
STEP1_PREREQS ?=
STEP2_PREREQS ?= step1
STEP3_PREREQS ?= step2

step1: $(STEP1_PREREQS)
    recipe1

step2: $(STEP2_PREREQS)
    recipe2

step3: $(STEP3_PREREQS)
    recipe3
```

Comment: it wasn't the order where local.make was included within common.make that stumped me but desire to avoid prerequisite-variable approach as mentioned in my question.  In addition, local.make also need to allow overriding of variables & recipes in common.make, so it can't be included at start of common.make.  Moreover, there are at least 3 dozens rules in the real common.make being used with some targets having multiple prerequisites.  Thus, using prerequisite-variable approach will become unwieldy, which is why I would like to avoid and hope for cleaner GNU make syntax solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can just add:

```
step1b: step1
    touch "$@"

step1c: step1b
    touch "$@"

step2: step1c
```

in local.make and call like this:

```bash
$ make step2; make -t step4; make step5
touch "step1"
touch "step1b"
touch "step1c"
touch "step2"
touch step3
touch step4
touch "step5"
```

(here to test the makefile I replace recipeN with `touch "$@"` so touch with quote is my recipe and touch without is printed by GNU Make.)

I know it works because it is very linear. If it doesn't I might just capture target list with `make -n` or something similar and do a command line like this.

What if instead of overriding you defined: step1.make step2.make
and you include them all. If you generate them by script then it is fine: you modify stepN.make but not the global one that include everybody. And the user could then choose to override precisely which step he wants.

So Makefile will have this shape:

```
# WARNING feel free to modify this file but don't modify stepN.make
#
# If you have missing target double check it isn't defined
# in stepN.make directly or with pattern (%) rule
include step1.make
include step2.make
include step3.make
```